# How to ignore a wordpress permalink and use the folder path instead

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site but want to have another microsite within one of the folders.

www.example.com = main site
www.example.com/shop = new site

However on the main site I have pretty permalinks turned on, how do I make an exception for just "shop". Below isnt working.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/shop
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
```

Comment: What if you move the shop block before the wordpress block?

Comment: Strange, there's an improvement but now Im getting 500 Internal error when I load the shop url

Comment: RewriteEngine On is before the RewriteCond?

Comment: yep I moved the two last lines to right after `RewriteEngine On` and before `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Yes, I've checked, and server  made a boo boo. I hope some more expert guy will help you.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit more digging on rewrites and .htaccess this code worked in the end...
Its simply saying if the url is shop stop any more rewrites

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^shop\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```